# Why can't I assign hash to a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables

I need to convert this:

```
prev = {in_progress: 1, todo: 3, done: 1}
```

Into this

```
output = {[ ['Status', 'Count'], ['Todo', 3], ['In Progress', 1], ['Done', 1] ]}
```

When I'm trying to assign `prev` to a variable, it gets assigned.

```
let a = {in_progress: 1, todo: 3, done: 1}
```

Success.

But when im trying to assign `output` to a variable, it throws an error

```
let a = {[ ['Status', 'Count'], ['Todo', 1], ['In Progress', 2], ['Done', 3] ]}

Error: 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
```

Can you explain the reason behind this?

Comment: That's simply a syntax error. You've got an array initializer inside `{ }` without a property name.

Comment: You just typed a floating matrix in an object without a key, thus the error... but, why did you call it hash?

Comment: It seems to me that a better DS would be: `let a = [ { status: 'Todo', count: 1 }, { status: 'In Progress', count: 2 }, { status: 'Done', count: 3 } ]` ... just an array of objects

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes probably need that format for a table script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `{[ ['Status', 'Count'], ['Todo', 3], ['In Progress', 1], ['Done', 1] ]}` is not a valid object literal. It's just curly braces around a list of lists. Object literals have to have key: value pairs.

If you wanted to turn it into an object, it would look like `{ 'Status': 'Count', 'Todo': 3, 'In Progress': 1, 'Done': 1 }`.

If you already have the list of lists and want to turn it into an object programmatically, you can do that with `reduce`:

```
// Note: no braces
let kvlist = [ ['Status', 'Count'], ['Todo', 3], ['In Progress', 1], ['Done', 1] ];
let obj = kvlist.reduce((h,[k,v]) => { h[k] = v; return h },{});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the entries and map the formatted key with the value.

```js
const format = s => s.split('_').map(([c, ...s]) => [c.toUpperCase(), ...s].join('')).join(' ');

var prev = { in_progress: 1, todo: 3, done: 1 },
    result = [
        ['Status', 'Count'],
        ...Object.entries(prev).map(([k, v]) => [format(k), v])
    ];

console.log(result);
```